# How to get field value after getting a node?

Tags: entities, nodes

I have a content type which contains school information. School name and school id are two fields in the content type. I have the school ID and I am able to retrieve the node. How do I get the school name? Below is how I retrieve the particular school node. I used the getValue() to retrieve the school name however, I get an empty array as a response for that. I am able to see the school name if I var_dump the school node.

```
$schoolNode = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('node')
      ->loadByProperties(['field_school_id' => $item['schoolId']]);
$schoolNode->field_school_name->getValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use node object from entityTypeManager, you need to get current value from the array after loading like below:

```
$schoolNode = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('node')
      ->loadByProperties(['field_school_id' => $item['schoolId']]);
$node_load = current($schoolNode);
$schoolname = $node_load->field_school_name->getValue();
```

This is only for a single node. If you have multiple nodes, foreach node as

```
foreach(schoolNode as $node){
  $schoolname = $node->field_school_name->getValue();
}
```